# Can a new Node for Compositor be implemented as an add-on? (vs. modifying Blender code)

Tags: compositing-nodes, development

My goal is to add a new Node to Compositor. Currently it does nothing but I can already add it from the Shift+A menu... wowewow, great success!

**Is it be possible to deliver the new Node as an add-on, rather than modifying Blender itself?**

Why I'd prefer an add-on:
My skill-level in C is pretty much non-existing, so the resulting commit would stink to high heaven and is unlikely to pass any code-review during the PR. But I don't want to work in my own custom-built Blender, and would much prefer to have the Node as an add-on which I can simply install whenever I download a new version of Blender.

Comment: No. It is not possible to do this.  You can't create new nodes in Python, and you can't distribute C level modifications as add-ons.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you